# Android - Use parse and ui test

Tags: android, parse-platform, ui-testing, android-espresso

I use [parse](http://www.parse.com) for push notifications and I want to mock it responses for my tests with espresso :)

I don´t want to create variables based on buildTypes on anything like that, I´m searching a cleaner way or parse supports it?

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating my own facade class and I mock that.